# How to get thread info in Dart?

Tags: dart

I need to get id of the current thread in Dart.  Something similar to how I would do this in Java (or C#):

```
Thread.currentThread().getId()
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Dart does not have threads, so maybe there is something else you can use to solve the same problem.

Answer (score 7):

Coming in a bit late but I think `Isolate.current.debugName` should give you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the Process ID of the running program? Because that is possible with the pid property from dart:io:

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.1/dart-io/pid.html

Comment: A process can have many threads,  I am specifically looking for the current thread id, inside the process

Comment: @WheelBuilder Dart doesn't expose threads.  It uses isolates, which *might* run in a separate thread or in a separate process. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11364519/179715

Comment: You can use the Dart Observatory for debugging: https://dart-lang.github.io/observatory/get-started.html